# PHPExcel can't save the file in browser

Tags: php, jquery, phpexcel

I'm trying to code a function in PHP to export some data to Excel file. The problem is if I save it to the server it does work, but if I try to send to the browser using php://output it just doesn't work. It doesn't even show the download window. I' ve been getting these as response:

> PK����a�B%���a��������[Content_Types].xml͔]K�0���%��f�
> "�v��R���kX����׿�m��+����4�<�'��2�jgs6�,+��v����Sz���a�����tr5^�=Bb�9+c����,��9��.T"�kXr/�J,���[.��`ck6�?h�\��,���ܠ}3�c�C+��9�-E��|c�j�BKPN�+�d��u��O1�
> o��Ba +���G

Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);



date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Rome');

require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; 
/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
include 'Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';



$target ='templates/';
$fileType = 'Excel2007';   
$InputFileName = $target.'richiesta.xlsx';   
$OutputFileName = $target     .'Richiesta_'.$_SESSION['User'].'_'.$_SESSION['Last'].'_'.$dat.'.xlsx';



//Read the file (including chart template) 
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType); 
//$objReader->setIncludeCharts(TRUE);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($InputFileName); 

 //Change the file 


$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
// Add data
            ->setCellValue('C3','10' )
            ->setCellValue('C4','20' )
            ->setCellValue('C5','30')
            ->setCellValue('C5','40' );


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, $fileType);

//$objWriter->save($OutputFileName);  //This one WORKS FINE!!!




header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="Report.xlsx"');


$objWriter->save('php://output'); //NOT WORKING :-(
```

Comment: Please review this answer. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560108/phpexcel-download-the-excel-file-on-the-client-side)

Comment: @TansukhRathod
I followed it, but still got the error. I got the same error as the ticket

PKݴTR$�Hp�[Content_Types].xml���N�0E�|E�-Jܲ@5��*Q>�ؓƪ_g���$R�v'J�=���&.....